# Tailwind.min.css overrides tailwind.css in my Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Whenever I try to configure Tailwind, so it accepts my custom font, it overrides the `tailwind.css` file with `tailwind.min.css`. Therefore, the changes don't show up.

[image]

Look, these are my files.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './components/**/*.{vue,js}',

    './layouts/**/*.vue',

    './pages/**/*.vue',

    './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',

    './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Rubik', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...,
  css: ["~assets/css/tailwind.css"],
  ...,
}
```

```css
/*@/assets/css/tailwind.css*/
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    src: url(../fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf);
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    src: url(../fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf);
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    src: url(../fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf);
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

The fonts are located in the right place relative to tailwind.css.

Comment: What is your `nuxt.config.js` configuration here?

Comment: @kissu The second one, here: https://gist.github.com/sarrietav-dev/2cd090618baf720657ead92a45982388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through this issue today, I bet you created your nuxt app using "create-nuxt-app" command, and you chose TailwindCSS as UI framework, and started working on the starter template.

if this is the case, you will find a component named tutorial.vue, that component is calling calling tailwind.min.css as an external resource.

```
<link> href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.1.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

please remove it, and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by using a new font-family (I named it Rubik), and used it at a top level div:

```css
/*assets/css/tailwind.css*/
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    src: url(../fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf);
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    src: url(../fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf);
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    src: url(../fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf);
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

```js
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './components/**/*.{vue,js}',

    './layouts/**/*.vue',

    './pages/**/*.vue',

    './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',

    './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        rubik: ['Rubik', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

```
<!-- pages/index.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="font-rubik">
    <Tutorial />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({})
</script>
```